# Magento not displaying new lines or bullet points on any pages

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, wysiwyg

I have a problem with Magento not displaying any html (Which I format in the WYSIWYG editor).

In the product description page for example, bold letters etc show but no bullet points and line breaks are made. So, all the text just appears in one paragraph.

Example:

My content looks like this

I have a new line with some:

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2

How it displays on my page is:

My content looks like this
I have a new line with some
bullet 1
bullet 2

Can anyone advise?

Comment: can you show your code for getting description?

Comment: Do share a Link AS well so that can view CSS

Comment: does solve your issue